# ignore mouse event on label inside panel

Tags: vb.net, hover, label, panel, mouseevent

I am making a custom menu. I am applying colors on panels on mouse enter and mouse leave.

I have labels on these panels, and the mouse enter and leave events work snappy, but as soon as I hover over the label (on/inside) the panel, the mouse leave event is fired. I know I can just do the same thing for the label mouse enter event, but I am doing some other visual stuff, and I need to have the label mouse events totally disregarded. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You disregard them by not using these events.  Not much left but using a Timer to find out where the mouse is located.  Or not using labels, they are expensive anyway and can easily be replaced by painting them in the paint event.

Comment: Hmmm, dit not think about painting them.... good idea. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually just used the menu control, and styled it accordingly. Does the job better than I could with code...