# C# mouse events on a panel don't apply to objects in panel

Tags: c#, events, mouseevent, mouse, mousedown

I am working on a simple C# program that allows the user to use the mouse to move simple controls (Buttons, textareas, etc), similar to a visual designer like visual studio. The controls are contained in a panel and they all work as expected. However, when I call `MouseDown()` on the panel the controls are contained in, the event only fires when clicking on an empty part of the panel, **not** when I click on a Control contained within the form.

Here is my `MouseDown()` Code:

```
 private void splitContainer2_Panel2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("MOUSE GRABBED");
            ...

            //More code that uses the X and Y co-ords of the mouse to check which
            //Control is selected
            ...
        }
```

As you can see it is very straightforward. The `writeLine()` is not triggered when I click on a control.

I have looked at questions such as:
[ignore mouse event on label inside panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541740/ignore-mouse-event-on-label-inside-panel)
To no avail.

Any help would be appreciated, even a better method to do what I am trying to acomplish.

Comment: Just to be helpful, don't use <code></code> tags for large bits of code, use the {} button instead. For small bits of code, you can use `code` (` = backtick). I have submitted an edit to this effect.

Comment: Thanky you for the info, I added your edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `MouseDown()` event for the panel, why not trying to use the same one for every object? Based on what you are trying to do, add the following code:

Where you create each form element:

```
nameOfElement.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.splitContainer2_Panel2_Objects_MouseDown);
```

The mouse down method:

```
Control ctrl = (Control)sender;
Console.WriteLine("Moused down on: " + ctrl.Name);
//Code to manipulate mouse down
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use `PreviewMouseDown`. The WPF hit testing engine will not raise events on parent elements if the child element absorbs the event.

Comment: This sounds good, however I can't seem to add the <code>previewMouseDown</code> to the panel, only preview key down. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: @user2837058: Are you using a `System.Windows.Controls.Panel`?